# Get two check-boxes value

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

I have two checkboxes which I have to run 3 different functions depending on what's checked by the user.

However I don't seem to be able to get the values correctly:

```js
    $('#checks').click(function() {
        if (!$('#different-billing-address').is(":checked") && $('#ccheck').is(":checked")) {alert("function1");}

        if ($('#different-billing-address').is(":checked") && !$('#ccheck').is(":checked")) {alert("function2");}

        if (!$('#different-billing-address').is(":checked") && !$('#ccheck').is(":checked")) {alert("function3");}

    });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="different-billing-address" data-multiplier="0.9" name="deliveryAddressSameAsBillingAddress" aria-expanded="false">
<label for="different-billing-address" class="checkbox-button">Delivery address is the same as billing address </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="ccheck" style="float:left;">
<label id="ocpc" class="checkbox-button">&nbsp;Get it delivered to an Order and Collection Point</label>
<br>
<button id="checks">MyButton</button>
```

Can someone explain to me why is this not working?

Comment: Please provide corresponding (minimum) HTML.

Comment: First, you need to provide the minimum "*[mcve]*" code so that we can reproduce your problem; then you need to explain, in words, what your code is supposed to be doing, and then you need to explain what is not doing, or what it is doing that it shouldn't be doing: we need to know what's wrong with your code before we can help you solve whatever the problem is. I'd suggest reading, or re-reading the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks fine. However, there's not enough information to tell why your code does not work. It could have been caused by one of the following:

1. Please include jQuery in the `head` section of your code or at the bottom but right before your code.
2. You need to enclose your code in **DOM ready** `$(function() { /* your code here */ });` to ensure your code fires when the `DOM` has loaded.

The following demo uses your logic and works fine.

```js
$(function() {
    var check1 = $('#different-billing-address'),
        check2 = $('#ccheck'),
        button = $('#checks');
    button.on('click', function() {
        if( !check1.is(':checked') && check2.is(':checked')  ) { console.log('Function1'); }
        if( check1.is(':checked') && !check2.is(':checked')  ) { console.log('Function2'); }
        if( !check1.is(':checked') && !check2.is(':checked') ) { console.log('Function3'); }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="different-billing-address" data-multiplier="0.9" name="deliveryAddressSameAsBillingAddress" aria-expanded="false">
<label for="different-billing-address" class="checkbox-button">Delivery address is the same as billing address </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="ccheck" style="float:left;">
<label id="ocpc" class="checkbox-button">&nbsp;Get it delivered to an Order and Collection Point</label>
<br>
<button id="checks">MyButton</button>
```